# FFMPEG - Combining one image and one audio together loop

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.mp3) DO ffmpeg -i "%%a" -f image2 -loop 1 -r 30 -i image.jpg -shortest -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast -vf scale=1280:720 "%%a.mp4"
pause
```

I have this batch code here, however it doesn't output correctly. The mp3 is successfully converted to a mp4, though the image is not merging with the audio.

I have the audio and the jpg called image.jpg in the folder together.

Comment: You probably just need to add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` output option.

Answer (score -1):

missing output -pix_fmt yuv420p
From Lordneckbeard